# Add workflow to a service dynamically in Symfony 6.3

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-workflows

The Symfony 6.3 [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/workflow.html) state concerning the workflow registry:

> Beware that injecting the Registry into your services is not
> recommended.

However, I need to get a specific workflow within a service method which decides which workflow to use based on a key. I don't know in advance which workflow to load, so I can't inject a specific workflow. How can I do this? For now, I inject the registry. Could I somehow inject the service_container and get it from there later?

Comment: simply use: https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow.html#accessing-the-workflow-in-a-class

Comment: That's exactly what my question said I can't do. I don't  know in advance which workflow I want to load, so I can't simply inject it.  My service has a method which processes a request, and then loads the intended workflow according to incoming data.

Comment: Lookup service locators. A locator is basically a subset of the registry. You build one with just workflow services, inject it and then pick the desired one from it.

Comment: sorry, the line i mean are above the linked target... you can use the service container like `$workflow = $this->container->get('workflow.your_workflow');`

Comment: @Cerad  Yes, that works.  One caveat is that I must know in advance if the workflow is a state_machine or a workflow, since they are keyed state_machine.xyz or workflow.xyz .  I guess I can work around that.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html for the service locators.

Comment: @Subcore your's unfortunately doesn't work, but thanks for the try.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Do you know the name of the needed workflow? If you know it, you can call it with the Target Attribute in your constructor. (use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\Target) 
```
    public function __construct(
        #[Target('character_lifecycle')]
        private WorkflowInterface $workflow,
    ) {
    }
```

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant In the yaml file, you define you use a unique key, and "type" is a subkey of each unique workflow. So I the unique key is something I  my service dynically gets from somewhere else, and I need it to get the workflow/state_machine by that key. See my solution below. The  point is, that I might change a state_machine into a workflow at some point. So if with "name" you mean then unique key, I have that (dynamically, not injectable), but I don't necessarily have workflow.xyz or state_machine.xyz. Again, I think my solution below explains it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Symfony 6.4 +

This works around what is probably a bug, namely that when you load a Workflow with a serviceLocator, it's key will be prefixed with 'debug.'
and the returned type is TraceableWorkflow. You can adjust this to your environment needs.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Container\NotFoundExceptionInterface;
use RuntimeException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\TaggedLocator;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\WorkflowInterface;

class WorkflowLoader
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly KernelInterface $kernel,
        #[TaggedLocator('workflow')] private readonly ContainerInterface $serviceLocator
    )
    {
    }

    public function getWorkflow($workflowName): WorkflowInterface
    {
        $prefix = '';
        if ($this->kernel->isDebug()) {
            $prefix = 'debug.';
        }
        try {
            if (!$workflow = $this->serviceLocator->get($prefix . 'state_machine.' . $workflowName)) {
                $workflow = $this->serviceLocator->get($prefix . 'workflow.' . $workflowName);
            }
        } catch (NotFoundExceptionInterface|ContainerExceptionInterface $e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Process Workflow $workflowName could not be loaded." . PHP_EOL . $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $workflow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use service locators to access every workflows.

It's mentioned in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow.html#accessing-the-workflow-in-a-class):

> If you want to retrieve all workflows, for documentation purposes for example, you can inject all services with the following tag:

```
workflow: all workflows and all state machine;
workflow.workflow: all workflows;
workflow.state_machine: all state machines.
```

It's possible to do it easily with Symfony 6/7 using locator attribute:

```
public function __construct(
    #[TaggedLocator('workflow')] private ContainerInterface $workflowsAndStateMachinesLocator,
    #[TaggedLocator('workflow.workflow')] private ContainerInterface $workflowsLocator,
    #[TaggedLocator('workflow.state_machine')] private ContainerInterface $stateMachinesLocator,
) {
}
```

Comment: This simply injects ALL workflows. It would be nice to be able to load only one according to calculated workflow key.

Comment: You mean injecting only one workflow depending on its name ? Then you can inject it using it's camelCase name or the target attribute ? But if your method have an argument which contains a string with your workflow name, then you need to use a service locator.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And I was wrong that this "injects ALL workflows". It Injects a service locator. So it's a good answer.

Comment: this is a bit overkill....

Comment: How so ? How would you get a specific workflow in a way that fit OP ?

Comment: @DylanKAS There is a major change in 6.4 which breaks this.
#[TaggedLocator('workflow')]  will only return   a service locator for debug.workflow.workflow.myWorkflow.  You can no longer a workflow with the service locator., only a DebuggerInterface.

Comment: Oh good to know, the doc doesn't mention any of this even for 6.4 https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/workflow.html#accessing-the-workflow-in-a-class it would be worth checking if the issue was just with the TaggedLocator

Comment: I have had to revert to using the registry. I can find no way to load a workflow dynamically otherwise. I image there is no real performance hit, so long there are not too many workflows.

Comment: @DylanKAS The problem is introduce in 6.4 with WorkflowDebugPass.php. If you comment it out, then your solution works again.

Comment: @DylanKAS And I think this is a bug, as the debug prefix disappears when env=prod . I was catching the bug by running my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Solution:

```
    #WorkflowLoader.php

WARNING: this no longer works as of Symfony 6.4

use Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Container\NotFoundExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\TaggedLocator;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\Workflow;
use RuntimeException;

class WorkflowLoader
{
    public function __construct(
        #[TaggedLocator('workflow')] private readonly ContainerInterface $serviceLocator
    )
    {
    }

    public function getWorkflow($workflowName): Workflow
    {
        try {
            if (!$workflow = $this->serviceLocator->get('state_machine.' . $workflowName)) {
                $workflow = $this->serviceLocator->get('workflow.' . $workflowName);
            }
        } catch (NotFoundExceptionInterface|ContainerExceptionInterface $e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Process Workflow $workflowName could not be loaded. \n" . $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $workflow;
    }
}
```

Comment: (I didn't downvote) IMHO, you should call "workflow" with the target attribute instead of taggedLocator, then find the needed workflow with its name as soon as you get it.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreTranchant for our comment. I don't understand what you mean with " call "workflow" with the target attribute". I can't inject the workflow itself, since I don't know its name yet. That's the whole point of the excecise.

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant Basically, my service has a method, which determines which workflow the Service needs, so I don't know the workflow name at __construct time. So the service locator is a good solution.

Comment: I am sorry, I was mistaken. I assumed that one should avoid injecting the ContainerInterface. It was a Symfony 3 bad practice to constantly rely on it. I thought you had to inject `#[Target('workflow')] WorkflowInterface $workflow`, and that it would allow you to loop through the workflows until you find the right one. But I was wrong. It's not possible. Your method is indeed the correct one. ServiceLocator seems to be the best solution. :)